# Policy in Minimal API - OR condition

Tags: c#, authorization, .net-6.0, minimal-apis

I have a very simple minimal API (.NET 6 with JWT Authentication Scheme) with 5 endpoints which:

- 2 are **read**, protected by a "ReadScope"
- 3 are **write**, protected by a "WriteScope"

```
app.MapGet("v1/getpet", GetPet)
    .RequireAuthorization("ReadOperation")

app.MapDelete("v1/deletepet", DeletePet)
   .RequireAuthorization("WriteOperation")
```

I'm also building my policies from *app.settings*:

```
{
  "SecurityPolicies": {
    "WriteOperation": {
      "PolicyName": "WriteOperation",
      "ClientScopes": [ "WriteScope" ]
    },
    "ReadOperation": {
      "PolicyName": "ReadOperation",
      "ClientScopes": [ "ReadScope" ]
    }
}
```

and this is part of my extension method:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    foreach (var policy in policies)
    {
        var policyBuilder = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder();

        if (policy.ClientScopes is not null && policy.ClientScopes.Any())
        {
            policyBuilder.RequireClaim("scope", policy.ClientScopes);
        }

        options.AddPolicy(policy.PolicyName, policyBuilder.Build());
    }
});
```

These policies are working (if I give a client only the read scope all write endpoints give back a 403 status code), but I would like to create a new policy called "FullAccess" which gives full access to all endpoints. I don't understand how I can do this with minimal API.

I read over other StackOverflow thread that I need some custom Handlers but they were explained over classic MVC API. I would like to implement something like "This endpoint requires FullAccess scope OR Write scope" and "This endpoint requires FullAccess scope OR Read scope"